# Matching expression context under `forall` with Ltac

Tags: coq, ltac

Say I have the following definitions in Coq:

```
Inductive Compare := Lt | Eq | Gt.

Fixpoint compare (x y : nat) : Compare :=
  match x, y with
  | 0, 0   => Eq
  | 0, S _ => Lt
  | S _, 0 => Gt
  | S x', S y' => compare x' y'
  end.
```

Now consider this lemma:

```
Lemma foo : forall (x: nat),
    (forall z, match compare x z with
               | Lt => False
               | Eq => False
               | Gt => False
               end) -> nat -> False.
Proof.
  intros x H y.
```

At this point proof state looks like this:

```
   x : nat
   H : forall z : nat,
       match compare x z with
       | Lt => False
       | Eq => False
       | Gt => False
       end
   y : nat
   ============================
   False
```

I'd like to write Ltac `match goal` that will detect that:

a) there is a hypothesis `x : nat` that is used as an argument to `compare` somewhere inside a quantified hypothesis `H`

b) and there is some other hypothesis of type `nat` - namely `y` - that can be used to specialize the quantified hypothesis.

c) and once we have those two things specialize `H` to `y`

I tried doing it like this:

```
 match goal with
 | [ X : nat, Y : nat
   , H : forall (z : nat), context [ compare X z ] |- _ ] => specialize (H Y)
 end.
```

But there are at least two things that are wrong with this code:

1. Using `context` under a `forall` seems disallowed.
2. I can't figure out a correct way to pass `X` as argument to `compare`
    in a way that it is recognized as something that exists as a hypothesis.doing it like this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that `X` occurs in the quantified hypothesis `H`, it suffices to check that it occurs in H after it is instantiated with any value that does not contain `X`.  For instance, you can instantiate `H` with `Y` by simply writing the application of `H` as a function to `Y`.  Here is my proposal:

```
match goal with | X : nat, H : _, Y : nat |- _ =>
  match type of (H Y) with | context[X] => specialize (H Y) end
end.
```

This Ltac text really checks that H is a function.  If you want to be more precise and state that `H` should really be a universal quantification (or a product type), then you can check that the type of `(H Y)` also contains `Y`, as in the following fragment:

```
match goal with | X : nat, H : _, Y : nat |- _ =>
  match type of (H Y) with | context[X] => 
    match type of (H Y) with | context [Y] => specialize (H Y) end
  end
end.
```

Comment: Not perfect, but it does the job. Thank you! BTW. Can you explain the meaning of `match type`? Is this documented anywhere in Coq manual?

Comment: Here you have the combination of two constructs of the Ltac language. <code>match ...with</code> and <code> type of </code>.  If you write <code>match H with</code> you only look at the symbol <code>H</code>, on the other hand, if you want to observe the hypothesis statement, you have to look at its type.  This is documented in section 9 of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't quite do what you are asking for, but it's somewhat close:

```
match goal with
| [ X : nat, Y : nat, H : context[compare ?a _] |- _ ] =>
  match type of H with
  | forall (z: nat), _ =>
    match a with
    | X => specialize (H Y)
    end
  end
end.
```

However, this does not check that the second argument to `compare` matches the `z` that is bound by the `forall`.

Comment: The more important part for me is detecting that `X` is the first argument to `compare` - otherwise how do I know whether to specialize for `X` or `Y`? Relying solely on their ordering in the context will be very fragile.